# How to plot on a curved plane?

Tags: plotting

I'm ploting the phase space of a pendulum problem using a symplectic Euler scheme.

$\qquad H = \frac{1}{2}p^2 - \cos q$, where $\dot{p}=-\sin q$ and $\dot{q}=p$

```
h=0.2; (*time step*)
p[0]=0.0; (*initial conditions*)
q[0]=0.5;

p[i_] := p[i] = p[i - 1] - h*Sin[q[i - 1]];
q[i_] := q[i] = q[i - 1] + h*p[i - 1] - h^2*Sin[q[i - 1]];

ListPlot[Table[{p[i], q[i]}, {i, 0, 100}], Frame -> True]
```

gives

[image: phase space plot]

Since the vector field is $2π$-periodic in `q`, it is natural to consider `q` as a variable on the circle $S^1$, I'd expect it to look something like

[image]

Any suggest how to do it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "curved plane". If want to plot on a 2-manifold, please give a description of the manifold in Wolfram Language code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it is indeed a duplicate, I'm happy with the solution provided, feel free to close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`h = 0.2;
p[0, a_] := 0;
q[0, a_] := a
p[i_, a_] := p[i, a] = p[i - 1, a] - h*Sin[q[i - 1, a]];
q[i_, a_] := 
q[i, a] = q[i - 1, a] + h*p[i - 1, a] - h^2*Sin[q[i - 1, a]];`

`plots = Table[
ListPointPlot3D[
Table[{Sin[q[i, a]], Cos[q[i, a]], p[i, a]}, {i, 0, 100}], 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.008], 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-3, 3}}], {a, 0.5, 3, 0.5}];`

`Show[plots, 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -3}, {0, 0, 3}}]}]]`

[image]